# Как получить доступ к публичному свойству класса из другого класса? C#

Tags: c#, синтаксис, property

Как получить доступ к публичному свойству класса из другого класса в C#? Чтобы было понятнее, т.к. я только начинаю изучать программирование, есть класс `Support` в котором есть метод `Stats`, он выводит значение свойства `Time` которое находится в классе `Configuration`, как можно это сделать?

```
    using System;
    namespace COOKING_GAME
    {
        public class Support
        {
            public static void Stats()
            {
            Console.WriteLine("+--------------------+\n" +
                          "You are living: " + ); //Сюда надо вставить Time из класса Configuration
            }
        }

        public class Configuration
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Money { get; set; } = 100; //IN ROUBLES
            public int Time { get; set; } //IN HOURS
        }
    }
```

Comment: помимо классов вам бы еще их экземпляры не помешали. Либо свойства должны быть статическими

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы обратиться к `public` свойству класса из другого класса, в Вашем случае необходимо сначала создать экземпляр класса:

```
public static void Stats()
{
     Configuration config = new Configuration()
     { 
        Time = 15 
     };
     Console.WriteLine("+--------------------+\n" +
               "You are living: " + config.Time); 
}
```

Также можно обратиться к свойству класса из другого без создания экземпляра, но при этом данное свойство должно быть статическим (`static`). В общем виде вызов такого свойства выглядит так: `ClassName.PropertyName`.
В Вашем случае:

```
public class Support
{
    public static void Stats()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("+--------------------+\n" +
                  "You are living: " + Configuration.Time);
    }
}

public class Configuration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; } = 100; //IN ROUBLES
    public static int Time { get; set; } //IN HOURS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Configuration config = new Configuration() { Time = 123 };
Console.WriteLine("+--------------------+\n" +
  "You are living: " + config.Time.ToString());
```

или

```
public static void Stats(Configuration aConfig)
{
    Console.WriteLine("+--------------------+\n" +
      "You are living: " + aConfig.Time.ToString()); 
}
```